# Python: getting file names using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have thousands of these lines in a list:

> [/usr/local/sa/ftp/collectorftp/AVideoP05D20160608000020E310.txt.gz,
>   /usr/local/sa/ftp/collectorftp/AHTTPP05D20160608000008E307.txt.gz,
>   /usr/local/sa/ftp/collectorftp/AVideoP05D20160608000122E322.txt.gz]

I need to get just filenames i.e

> AVideoP05D20160608000020E310.txt.gz AHTTPP05D20160608000008E307.txt.gz
>   AVideoP05D20160608000122E322.txt.gz

Do I need to use regular expressions? Or do we have easier way to do it?

thx

Comment: `item.rsplit('/')[-1]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thx. It really worked.I just did not understand why my question was highly downvoted. This discourage beginners asking questions. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Because you asked a question *with absolutely no evidence of any effort on your part*. You just dumped in your problem and expected people to spend their free time solving it for you. Read [ask] before posting again, and try to implement things yourself first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, based on my experience in searching I've seen lot of "basic" questions like that so I assumed I could do it. But now I completely understood. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `split`:

```
name.split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use the right tool for the job.

**Much safer option** is to use `os.path.basename(..)` than `string.split(..)`

```
>>> import os
>>> paths = "/usr/local/sa/ftp/collectorftp/AVideoP05D20160608000020E310.txt.gz, /usr/local/sa/ftp/collectorftp/AHTTPP05D20160608000008E307.txt.gz, /usr/local/sa/ftp/collectorftp/AVideoP05D20160608000122E322.txt.gz".split(", ")
>>> map(os.path.basename, paths)
['AVideoP05D20160608000020E310.txt.gz', 'AHTTPP05D20160608000008E307.txt.gz', 'AVideoP05D20160608000122E322.txt.gz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need a regex for this. A *rightward* split on `'/'` should do:

```
[i.rsplit('/')[-1]  for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task to do using the split operator. All you need to do is the following:

```
[item.split('/')[-1] for item in you_list]
```

This will take each item in the list an splits the item using `/`, -1 will be the last item of the list which is the result of split.

Comment: How is this different from the answer @MosesKoledoye posted a minute back?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I guess we all sent our answers at the same time.

Comment: Thx guys. It worked as well. Sorry for basic question anyway.